# How To Place Multiple Gantt Chart Bars On Same Row?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, series, gantt-chart

I currently have a gantt chart that displays dates of work requests. I've been asked to modify the gantt chart to only display the days work will be performed. For example, WR #1 begins 2/8/2016 and ends 2/25/2016. However, work is only performed Mon-Thur. My current gantt chart shows a bar from 2/8/2016 to 2/25/2016. I would like to break up the bar so that it only displays 2/8-2/11, 2/15-2/18, and 2/22-2/25. I would also like to display this single work request on one line. Is it possible to use `SeriesChartType.RangeBar` for this, or do I have to use a different chart type? I tried to create a series using multiple `DataPoint` objects with the same `xValue`, however when I added the series to the chart each `DataPoint` was displayed on a separate row. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Here is some code I am using for my chart setup:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
...
Series series1 = new Series();
series1.ChartArea = "Default";
series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;
series1.YValuesPerPoint = 2;
series1.YValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
```

First attempt:

```
// WR #1
DataPoint dp0 = new DataPoint(0, new double[] { startDate0, stopDate0 });
DataPoint dp1 = new DataPoint(0, new double[] { startDate1, stopDate1 });
DataPoint dp2 = new DataPoint(0, new double[] { startDate2, stopDate2 });

// WR #2
DataPoint dp3 = new DataPoint(1, new double[] { startDate3, stopDate3 });
DataPoint dp4 = new DataPoint(1, new double[] { startDate4, stopDate4 });
DataPoint dp5 = new DataPoint(1, new double[] { startDate5, stopDate5 });

series1.Points.Add(dp0);
series1.Points.Add(dp1);
series1.Points.Add(dp2);
series1.Points.Add(dp3);
series1.Points.Add(dp4);
series1.Points.Add(dp5);

chart1.Series.Clear();
chart1.Series.Add(series1);
```

I have a few hundred work requests, so naturally I will use a loop to create each `DataPoint` for each work request and add it to the series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1, new object[] { new DateTime(2016, 2, 8), new DateTime(2016, 2, 25) });
        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(2, new object[] { new DateTime(2016, 2, 8), new DateTime(2016, 2, 11) });
        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(2, new object[] { new DateTime(2016, 2, 15), new DateTime(2016, 2, 18) });
        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(2, new object[] { new DateTime(2016, 2, 22), new DateTime(2016, 2, 25) });
    }
```

[image]